# Centering text at the top of the header

Tags: text-decorations

I'm using the following to create this header:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=0.5cm, right=1.1cm, top=-1cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym} % for icons
\usepackage{url} % for e-mail address
\usepackage{sectsty}  % for customizing section font

\sectionfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

% Horizontal rule
\newlength{\normalrulethickness}
\setlength{\normalrulethickness}{0.4pt}
\newcommand{\thinrule}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{\normalrulethickness}}
\newcommand{\thickrule}{\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{2\normalrulethickness}}
\newcommand{\doublerule}{%
    \thickrule%
    \llap{\rule[2pt]{\linewidth}{\normalrulethickness}}%
}

\newcommand{\letterhead}{%
    \noindent%
    \textbf{\department}\hfill \textbf{\university}\newline
    \course\hfill \documentname\hfill \subject\newline
    \doublerule\par\smallskip
    {\small\noindent%
    \professor\hfill 
        %\emailicon\ 
        %\email\hfill 
        %\phoneicon\
        %\phone\hfill
        \office%
    }\par\bigskip%
}

\newcommand{\setdepartment}[1]{\gdef\department{#1}}
\newcommand{\setuniversity}[1]{\gdef\university{#1}}
\newcommand{\setcourse}[1]{\gdef\course{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsubject}[1]{\gdef\subject{#1}}
\newcommand{\setdocumentname}[1]{\gdef\documentname{#1}}
\newcommand{\setprofessor}[1]{\gdef\professor{#1}}
\newcommand{\setemail}[1]{\gdef\email{\url{#1}}}
\newcommand{\setphone}[1]{\gdef\phone{#1}}
\newcommand{\setoffice}[1]{\gdef\office{#1}}

% Icons in letterhead
\newcommand{\emailicon}{\Email} % from marvosym
\newcommand{\phoneicon}{\Telefon}

\newcommand{\pointvalue}[1]{\hfill\mbox{#1}}
\newcommand{\strong}[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\setdepartment{TEXT 1}
\setuniversity{TEXT 2}
\setcourse{TEXT 3,TEXT 3, TEXT 3}
\setsubject{TEXT 4}
\setdocumentname{TEXT 5}
\setprofessor{TEXT 6}
%\setemail{}
%\setphone{}
\setoffice{TEXT 7}

\letterhead

\end{document}
```

However, text 5 is not centered when adding more text to text 3. I've tried to center text 5 but it creates much space between the rule.

What's the best way to center text 5 despite adding more text to text 3 or text 4?

Comment: You could put text3 and text4 into an `makebox` of zero width.  So put `\makebox[0pt][l]{\course}\hfill` in the header...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to center the document name, regardless of the size of the course name or the subject, you can replace this line

```
\course\hfill \documentname\hfill \subject\newline
```

with

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{\course}\hfill \documentname\hfill \makebox[0pt][r]{\subject}\newline
```

in your definition of `\letterhead`.  This produces:

[image]

Comment: Note that I changed `top=-1cm` in the OP MWE to `top=1cm` in order to produce the answer above.